# In the movie Interstellar, if Cooper and Brand were to transmit video footage from Miller's Planet to the Endeavour, what would Romilly see?

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, relativity, time-dilation

This question is with regard to Miller's planet, where 1 hour is equivalent to 7 earth hours. Dr. Brand and Cooper are present on the surface of the planet, whereas Romilly is on the Endeavour.

From what I have read, if Romilly wanted to look at the planet with a telescope, he would first need to overcome certain problems. First, by virtue of red-shift, the visible light would be shifted into the infrared region. Additionally, the light may appear distorted.

But, if Romilly were to overcome these problems, he would be able to see the events on Miller's planet in extreme slow motion.

However, my question has to do with **video footage**.

If (hypothetically) video footage were to be transmitted from Miller's planet in real time, would Romilly still see the events in slow-mo (as with the telescope) or in real time? If Romilly were capable of seeing the video footage **in real time**, he would be able to see the future!

Please, while answering this question, **ignore the practicality** of this and assume that video footage is successfully transmitted to Romilly on the Endeavour.

Answer (score 1):

In slow motion. You basically answer the question yourself:

> If Romilly were capable of seeing the video footage **in real time**, he would be able to see the future!

Relativity does not permit us to see into the future, and so the video footage must be in slow motion.

Comment: What would the total amount of information telemetered be though?  Suppose the transmit a 10 MB video from the ground, would it still be 10 MB upon arrival?  If so, why would the playback be in slow motion?  Would the frame rate be the cause of the slower playback on the spacecraft?  I am not sure one could send a real-time telemetry stream under these conditions in human readable format but a pre-recorded video should transmit fine, correct?

Comment: I believe the question was about watching the video footage "live", or in "real" time as it arrived.

Comment: @honeste_vivere As Tom says, the question is about watching the video as it arrives. You could of course wait and watch it in full speed later.

Comment: Ah, okay yes that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The signal transmitting the video would be subject to the same physical conditions as the light travelling to the telescope. So the video would be in slow motion too.